# Proxmox: Unidentified network on each reboot for Windows hosts

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, proxmox

Since about 1 year I always have the same error with Windows guests: on each reboot, Windows says the network is unidentified. So the network card is named "Ethernet 8" then "Ethernet 9" then "Ethernet 10" etc.

Hosts are Debian Jessie, and Proxmox installed following the very simple official guide.
Guests are Windows 2012R2 and Windows 2016 (I currently don't have other flavours).

I have the same behaviour:

- with Intel E1000 or the paravirtualised drivers (I have not tested others)
- with all our Windows guests. Test, production, no exception
- with guests installed 1 year ago, and guest installed yesterday on a fresh host

I searched the web and did not found anything valuable.
As it is occuring to me every time, either I make a mistake, either it is common. But as search engines give me nothing, I suspect a mistake.

@Michael Hampton: the MACs are fixed, as for every virtual machines I know. I just verified on the new guest, and no change accros reboots.

Comment: Are your systems in an AD domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Proxmox's forum](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/windows-unidentified-network-on-each-reboot.40901/), I solved the problem by delaying the start of "NLA (Network Location Awareness)".

```
sc config nlasvc start= delayed-auto
```

So this could be some race condition?

Answer (score 0):

The source of this problem is that Proxmox changes the MAC address of the bridge when a VM starts.
You can overcome this by setting a fixed MAC address via statement 'bridge_hw'.
For example in your '/etc/network/interfaces' file:

```
# Device: vmbr0
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
  bridge_ports none
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_fd 0
  bridge_hw 00:16:3e:ff:a5:a3
  address 192.168.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.0.0
  broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

For more information see this: https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/static-mac-for-vmbr.33534/